# for a simple hotspot from mobile how to understand the netstat result

Tags: networking, gateway

I have a mobile and hotspot is on. I connected by linux laptop to that hotspot.

Now on my linux computer i run the commands

```
$ netstat -r -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp3s0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
```

and my ip is 192.168.43.193

```
$ ipconfig -a
wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.193  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 2409:4070:2201:c42b:1a38:21df:c868:7fde  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::25ac:4aff:2683:9be8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ac:d1:b8:47:a4:47  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 408640  bytes 476371745 (454.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 287073  bytes 40393931 (38.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Now how to understand netstat output.

As per my understanding:

```
Any ip with `192.168.43.0/255` does not have a gateway or gateway of `0.0.0.0`

Any ip will have a gateway of `192.168.43.1`
```

It does not make sense once we say `Any ip  the gateway is 192.168.43.1` and again we say `Any ip with 192.168.43.0/255 does not have a gateway or gateway of 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Since it's Linux, you should be looking at `ip route` and `ip addr` output nowadays...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ip with `192.168.43.0/255`

The 'slash' syntax indicates the number of network bits (based on the netmask), **not** the start–end range. If you convert netmask 255.255.255.0 to binary you'll see that it has 24 "on" bits, so the network should be written as `192.168.43.0/24`.

(That said, full netmask `192.168.43.0/255.255.255.0` will also be understood by most.)

> does not have a gateway or gateway of `0.0.0.0`

Yes – it's a route without a gateway, which means the addresses are "on-link": directly reachable at MAC layer. In other words, this is your local subnet route.

Although it's the lack of `G` flag that matters; it doesn't matter that old tools still show 0.0.0.0 in the gateway column (they could show nothing instead).

> Any ip will have a gateway of `192.168.43.1`

Yes – but **only if** that IP did not match the 192.168.43.0/24 route first.

> It does not make sense

It does, because routes are checked in certain order and the **most specific** route always wins. ("Most specific" is based on netmask bits, e.g. a /24 route wins over a /16 route, and all of them win over the 0.0.0.0/0 route. That's why the latter is called "default route" – it's checked last, when nothing else fits.)

So when looking at 0.0.0.0/0, you can mentally add "any IP *which did not match any other route* has a gateway 192.168.43.1".

Comment: `"Most specific" is based on netmask bits, e.g. a /24 route wins over a /16 route, and all of them win over the 0.0.0.0/0 route`. So this is how the order is followed. Thank you. Now it makes sense.

Comment: `Although it's the lack of G flag that matters;`: will there be any case with `U` and also Gateway is not 0.0.0.0